# Extracting slices that are identical between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I combine 2 dataframe `df1` and `df2` in order to get `df3` that has the rows of `df1` and `df2` that have the same index (and the same values in the columns)?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A2', 'A3', 'A7'],
                        'B': ['B0', 'B2', 'B3', 'B7'],
                        'C': ['C0', 'C2', 'C3', 'C7'],
                        'D': ['D0', 'D2', 'D3', 'D7']},
                         index=[0, 2, 3,7])
```

## test 1

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A7'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B7'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C7'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D7']},
                     index=[0, 1, 2, 7])
```

## test 2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1'],
                    'B': ['B1'],
                    'C': ['C1'],
                    'D': ['D1']},
                     index=[1])
```

## Expected output test 1

```
Out[13]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
7  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

## Expected output test 2

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```

Comment: yes, an option could be to use concat, but it does not check the values..

Comment: Did any of our answers work?

Answer (score 1):

First, get the intersection of indices. Next, find all rows where all the columns are identical, and then just index into either dataframe.

```
idx = df1.index & df2.index
df_out = df1.loc[(df1.loc[idx] == df2.loc[idx]).all(1).index]

print(df_out)
```

You can also use `df.isin` (slightly different from the other answer):

```
df_out = df1[df1.isin(df2).all(1)]
print(df_out)
```

---

**Test 1**

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
7  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

**Test 2**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is amore pythonic solution:

```
df1[df2.isin(df1)].dropna()
```

gives:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
7  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()).set_index('index')
```

This adds the index of each dataframe as a column, then joins on all the columns (which now includes the index) and then sets the index to be back to the original values.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this .

**For test 1**

```
df1['index']=df1.index
df2['index']=df2.index
df1['Mark']=df1.apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
df2['Mark']=df2.apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
df1[df1.Mark.isin(df2.Mark)].drop(['Mark','index'],1)


Out[20]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
7  A7  B7  C7  D7
```

---

**For test 2**

```
Out[28]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```